# Why do POST request in the Go http.Client not follow 301 redirects?

Tags: http, go

I'm building a test tool with Go. This tool can retrieve a specific URL by doing a POST request to an endpoint which returns a 303 with the `Location` to test. Sometimes this location itself is redirected with a 301 which I want to follow as well.

```
Test tool -> POST /get-url-to-test -> 303 Location: /other -> GET /other -> 301 Location: /new-other (stops here because initial request is POST)
```

As we can see in Go's source (lines 241 to 257), it seems like GET requests follow 301 redirects, but not POST requests:
http://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go

Why is that? Is that part of an HTTP spec? Is this an decision that was made by the Go community?

The reason I'm asking is because in my case, I'd have to manually do a new GET request to get to the URL redirected to by `/other`, I think.

---

EDIT 1: I made a mistake before: the `/other` resource is being fetched by Go with a GET request. But since it returns a 301 and the initial request was a POST, Go stops redirecting on the 301. That seems odd. Am I missing something?

EDIT 2: This may be a bug, I've opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9348

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: Thanks @nos. That's interesting. Didn't know about 307. However, the problem here is that Go does not redirect a GET request that landed on a 301. That seems very odd. If you do a POST that lands on a 303, Go redirects you to the `Location` with the GET method, but if that `Location` itself returns a 301, than Go stops redirecting, even though we got there with a GET request.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be what the code does - when performing the rules for redirection at line 302 it passes in the rules for POST redirection (the shouldRedirectPost) function which makes sense for handling the 1. redirect. But that rule is also used on the subsequent GET requests after first GET redirect. I don't know if that is intentional, but it sounds like a bug.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your feedback on this. I'll report a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) says:

> 10.3 Redirection 3xx
>
> This class of status code indicates that further action needs to be taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request.  The action required MAY be carried out by the user agent
>   without interaction with the user **if and only if the method used in
>   the second request is GET or HEAD**.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! After looking into it further, I made a mistake in my question: the `/other` resource is fetched with a `GET` request by Go (line 341 in the source). So I would have thought that the 301 should be followed too, no?

Comment: This is no longer the standard behaviour: RFC2616 is obsolete and has been replaced by RFC723x. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4

Comment: @Rick-777 Interesting, I'll have to go through that RFC. In the meantime, can you edit the answer and point specifically at the quote that obsoletes the 2616 behavior?